# Oracle 23c - Reuse WINDOW clause

Tags: oracle

I was going through the new analytical syntax enhancement in Oracle 23c, Which allows us to define `WINDOW` clause separately, something like this:

```
select ...., analytical_function over window_var
from ....
window window_var (partition by ... order by ....)
```

I realized that it is useful as it can be **reused** within the single query.

But When I have started using it, I found that it can not be re-used from inline or outer query (Even though same named column is available in both inline or outer queries). I want to reuse the window clause with my complex query defining it only once like CTE.

I tried following and with the given result:

```
-- Works fine -- Obviously
select t.*, row_number() over w as rn
  from abc t
window w as (partition by col1 order by id);


-- Works fine, Reused in the same SQL query
select t.*, row_number() over w as rn,
       sum(col1) over w
  from abc t
window w as (partition by col1 order by id);


-- ERROR -- Unable to reuse -- declaration at the end of entire query
-- ORA-32784: The window name referenced did not exist.
select t.*, sum(col1) over w from
(select t.*, row_number() over w as rn
  from abc t) t
 window w as (partition by col1 order by id);


-- ERROR -- Unable to reuse -- declaration inside the inline query
-- ORA-32784: The window name referenced did not exist.
select t.*, sum(col1) over w from
(select t.*, row_number() over w as rn
  from abc t
    window w as (partition by col1 order by id);
  ) t


-- Works fine -- Unable to re-use - multiple declaration of WINDOW clause
select t.*, sum(col1) over w from
(select t.*, row_number() over w as rn
  from abc t
    window w as (partition by col1 order by id)
  ) t
 window w as (partition by col1 order by id);
```

I have created sample [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZFr-0wVT) to help understand the issue better.

Is there any way, we can define `WINDOWS` clause only once and use it at different level in the same `SELECT` statement. (Considering that at all level of SQL, We have same named column available)

Comment: I think it can be difficult if you join multiple tables the these tables have same column names. Then the named window would be ambiguous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way, we can define `WINDOWS` clause only once and use it at different level in the same `SELECT` statement.

Summary: It would appear that you cannot.

---

The `SELECT` documentation states:

> #### `window_clause`
>
> Oracle Database Release 21c supports the `window_clause` in the `query_block` clause.
>
> ##### Rules
>
> - If you use a new `window_specification` to specify an `existing_window_name` then
>
>   - `existing_window_name` must refer to an earlier entry in the `window_name` list
>   - You cannot use `existing_window_name` with `windowing_clause`
>   - You cannot define a new window with the `query_partition_clause`. If `existing_window_name` has `order_by_clause`, then the new window definition cannot have `order_by_clause`.
> - You cannot use the `model_clause` with `window_clause`.
> - Note that `OVER window_name` is not equivalent to `OVER (window_name …)`. `OVER (window_name …)` implies copying and modifying the window specification, and will be rejected if the referenced window specification includes a `windowing_clause`.

The `query_block` clause referred to in the opening paragraph is a `SELECT` clause:

> [image: query_block clause]

That is the the extent of the official documentation that I have been able to find.

The implication is that the `window_clause` has the same scope as the `where_clause`, `hierarchical_query_clause`, `group_by_clause` and `model_clause` and applies **only** to the local `query_block` and windows defined in sub-queries and sub-query factoring clauses are out-of-scope.

Trying to use a sub-query factoring clause (a.k.a. `WITH` clause) and referencing the window as `sub_query_factoring_clause_alias.window_name`:

```sql
WITH sqfc AS (
  select t.*, row_number() over w as rn
  from abc t
  window w as (partition by col1 order by id)  
)
select sqfc.*,
       sum(col1) over sqfc.w
from   sqfc;
```

Raises the syntax error:

> ```
> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
> ```

And without the `sub_query_factoring_clause_alias` prefix:

```sql
WITH sqfc AS (
  select t.*, row_number() over w as rn
  from abc t
  window w as (partition by col1 order by id)  
)
select sqfc.*,
       sum(col1) over w
from   sqfc;
```

Raises the exception:

> ```
> ORA-32784: The window name referenced did not exist.
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YjfwEsPX)

---

Additionally, as [commented by @WernfriedDomscheit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77762989/oracle-23c-reuse-window-clause/77763494#comment137093973_77762989):

> I think it can be difficult if you join multiple tables the these tables have same column names. Then the named window would be ambiguous.

In a similar train-of-thought: if, hypothetically, the syntax did work and you had the query:

```sql
WITH sqfc AS (
  select t.*, row_number() over w as rn
  from abc t
  window w as (partition by col1 order by id)  
)
select sqfc.*,
       s.*,
       sum(col1) over sqfc.w
from   sqfc
       CROSS JOIN some_other_table s;
```

How would the window apply to the later query block because there is a different set of rows and columns generated by `CROSS JOIN`ing another table? The `SUM` over the window in the sub-query would be different to the `SUM` over the window in the outer query due to the extra rows.

This would appear to make the implementation of that syntax a very hard (impossible?) problem to solve as you would need the window to apply even if the rows change between sub-queries.